# Type Alias for Function Types in Scala

Tags: scala, function, types, functional-programming, alias

I'm newest in Scala language and I can't understand how `type Set = Int => Boolean` works. I understand that it's something integer conversing to Boolean. I have `def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = y => exists(s, x => y == f(x))` For exist `def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = !forall(s, i => !p(i))`) and

```
def forall(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def iter(a: Int): Boolean = {
      if (a > bound) true
      else if (diff(s,p)(a)) false
      else iter(a + 1)
    }
    iter(-bound)
  }
```

This two functions I understand but with `map` function I have a problem. I just don't understand how does it show answer if I call it `map(Set(2,3,5), i => i * 20)` . I get `{40,60,100}`. I have tried to understand it and I know that `x` is each element in `s` and `f(x)` is x elemet which multiply in 20. And `y` is range from -1000 to 1000 (`bound = 1000`). My reading this function like this:  `y` is range `-1000..1000` in exists function is getting our `Set(2,3,5)` and after it give somthing with `Boolean type`. And how am I getting  answer like `{40,60,100}`. How is new set creating there?

Full code ->

```
  type Set = Int => Boolean

  def contains(s: Set, elem: Int): Boolean = s(elem)
  def diff(s: Set, t: Set): Set = (i: Int)  => s(i) && !t(i)

  val bound = 1000

  def forall(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def iter(a: Int): Boolean = {
      if (a > bound) true
      else if (diff(s,p)(a)) false
      else iter(a + 1)
    }
    iter(-bound)
  }

  def exists(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = !forall(s, x => !p(x))
  def map(s: Set, f: Int => Int): Set = y => exists(s, x => y == f(x))

  def toString(s: Set): String = {
    val xs = for (i <- -bound to bound if contains(s, i)) yield i
    xs.mkString("{", ",", "}")
  }

  println(toString(map(Set(2, 3, 5), (i: Int) => i * 20)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the `map()` implementation...

```
y => exists(s, x => y == f(x))
```

...and the invocation...

```
map(Set(2,3,5), (i: Int) => i * 20)
```

...make a few substitutions, and you get:

```
val mappedSet = y => exists(Set(2,3,5), x => y == x*20)
```

As a `Set` is `Int => Boolean` (a function that takes an `Int` and returns **true** or **false**), `mappedSet` is a function that asks:

*Given a number, `y`, does there exist a number within +-bounds that both passes (is a member of) `Set(2,3,5)` and, when multiplied by 20, equals `y`?*

`mappedSet(60)` returns **true** because within +-bounds there *does* exist a number, `3`, that is both a member of `Set(2,3,5)` AND, when multiplied by 20, equals `60`.

`mappedSet(80)` returns **false** because no number can be found that passes both tests.

Comment: I see, thank you so much :) Maybe you can recommended me some books or sites where I will can more learn this language and this situation?